DNS Server Installation
Good day to you all.
I've some question to ask about dns server (Recursive DNS) installation as Internet Service Provider (ISP) environment. For IP address planning, i have two public IPs to use. I have register two public ip at dns control panel for (ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com). These two child domains are already public accessible (ns1.maykochi.com and dns.maykochi.com).
And the point is , what ip should i use when i create the zone. With public ip or private ip. When our user do nslookup i want them to see like this.
C:\Users\ACER>nslookup www.youtube.com
Server:  dns.maykochi.com
Address:  192.168.99.254

And one thing, I also want to know, when i create the forward zone and reverse zone with private ip (192.168.99.254), how to make it public accessible with dns.maykochi.com. Do i need to translate its with public ip (130.110.111.123). Thank you for everyone for your advice.
Forward Zone
$TTL 1D
@   IN  SOA ns1.maykochi.com.   admin.maykochi.com. (
                2024071001  ; serial
                1D      ; refresh
                1H      ; retry
                1W      ; expire
                3H )        ; minimum

        IN  NS  ns1.maykochi.com.
        IN  NS  dns.maykochi.com.

ns1     IN  A   130.110.111.122
dns     IN  A   130.110.111.123
www     IN  A   104.10.121.124
www         IN      CNAME   maykochi.com

Backward Zone
$TTL 1D
@   IN  SOA ns1.maykochi.com.   admin.maykochi.com. (
                2024071001  ; serial
                1D      ; refresh
                1H      ; retry
                1W      ; expire
                3H )        ; minimum

        IN  NS  ns1.maykochi.com.
        IN  NS  dns.maykochi.com.

122     IN  PTR ns1.maykochi.com.
123     IN  PTR dns.maykochi.com.
124     IN  PTR maykochi.com.


Which supported Ubuntu version are you using?

DNS points to IP's. It doesn't care about private or public IP space.

Split your individual questions up - you have multiple in one question.

I'm running on Ubuntu 22.04 ( BIND 9.18.24-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu (Extended Support Version)
